# Liquibase and system catalogs (PostgreSQL)

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, liquibase

I'm trying to include data from pg_catalog into my changelog files, but liquibase seems to completely ignore it.

```
this.liquibase.generateChangeLog(
            buildCatalogAndSchema(this.liquibase.getDatabase()), // postgres @ jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb (Default Schema: pg_catalog)
            new DiffToChangeLog(new DiffOutputControl(false, false, false, null)),
            new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(this.changeLog)),
            ChangeLogSerializerFactory.getInstance().getSerializer(this.changeLog),
            Optional.of(DatabaseObjectFactory.getInstance()
                .parseTypes(this.diffTypes)) //data
                .map(s -> s.toArray(new Class[s.size()]))
                .get()
        );
```

Here's the resulting changelog:

```
{ "databaseChangeLog": []}
```

As you can see liquibase is acting like the pg_catalog catalog doesn't exist, but it works fine with other non-system schemas. I'm using the superuser account so I have the privileges to read it. 
I've also tried to reach out to the liquibase team using their forums but in 20 days I got no response. Thanks for the help.